# Jnlp downloding certificate from server in https protocol

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-web-start, jnlp

WE are having a webstart application.
Currently it is running fine.
Our jnlp file has unsecure links ie) http://********

When i change this from http to https://********* we are getting ssl handshake error.
How to make this working.
I hope we should install the security certificate in the client machine but our system is vast sowe need to either download the certificate or skip the certifiate checking part while using https.

Currently we are in Java 6. We are going to Migrate our application to Java8
Can someone please suggest some solution.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question belongs to SuperUser as it is webserver-configuration related

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error and except that you get?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am getting the below Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Comment: Have you tried hosting it on other https servers with different certificates to see if the problem may be your server certificate? I couldn't find a solution online, looks like not many people host webstart on https so few complained about this. I think your best bet is to file a bug report with Oracle and have them verify it for you and either offer a solution or fix the bug if it is a bug.